# I cannot able to connect sublime text 2 from my terminal

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2

When I am writing open subl in my terminal it's showing The file /user/imtiaz/sublime does not exis can some one please help me for this one thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi matt I want to use sublime text 2 as a editor for my rails application on my mac I have already put a command to make a simbolick link with the terminal but it is still not working I want all my rails file to open in sublime text 2 for coding thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your account has administrator access, run the following command from Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

The `sudo` command will ask you to enter your password, which you should do. The symbolic link will be created in `/usr/bin`, which is already in your path. You should now be able to run

```
subl filename.ext
```

and open the filename in Sublime.

---

If you're just getting started with Sublime, however, I would **strongly** recommend using [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3) instead. It has many major improvements over ST2, and even though it's technically still labeled "Beta", it's rock-solid. I've been using it for over 2 years without any major issues. ST2 has some bugs in it, which will never get fixed. Once installed, the first thing you need to do is install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), which allows you to easily manage plugins. Many plugins now only support ST3, or their ST2 versions are no longer being updated.

If you do install ST3, change the above command to

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

as the app is named `Sublime Text.app` instead of `Sublime Text 2.app`.

Comment: Ok matt let me try this and I'll get back to you tommorrow thanks

Comment: Hi matt I have downloaded St 3 and run that command but still I cannot able to open my rails app folder in St 3    is there any thing eles I need to configure? Thanks

Comment: @imtiazahmed Please give **details**. Did you put `Sublime Text.app` in your `Applications` directory? Did you run the command I gave? What was its output? What command did you run to open your Rails project? What was its output?

Comment: Hi matt I tried again and it's working thanks for your help